# Efficient optimization function or package for maximization of multidimensional function

Tags: r, optimization

I am using optim() function to perform maximum likelihood for multidimensional functions. Below is the line of code involving optim:

```
mle<-optim(parameter, loglik, grad, method="BFGS", hessian=TRUE, x=X,y=Y)
```

The code works well but it is very slow in executing the optim() part. I would like to know if there is any optimization function(s)/ package(s) in R that is/ are more efficient and suitable for multidimensional functions, compared to optim. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check this one https://github.com/mlr-org/mlrMBO

Comment: Try to find a good initial point using a different technique (e.g. OLS)